# add to init function on UIButton extension

Tags: ios, swift, init

I want to add a custom init to the UIButton class using an extension

```
extension UIButton {
    init() {
        backgroundColor = InterfaceDesign.button.backgroundColor
        setTitleColor(InterfaceDesign.button.textColor, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

The first problem is this error:

> Designated initializer cannot be declared in an extension of 'UIButton'; did you mean this to be a convenience initializer?

Then if I click the red white dot to fix it, it inserts a convenience in front like so:

```
convenience init()
```

But then this error appers:

> Initializer 'init()' with Objective-C selector 'init' conflicts with implicit initializer 'init()' with the same Objective-C selector

I already tried googling it but only found working code for subclasses of uibutton...

Thanks for your help

Comment: What you want to do in `init()` function ?

Comment: @SagarChauhan I want to style the button (set background color etc.)

Comment: From Swift docs https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html : `NOTE: Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality.`

Comment: @swiftlynx,You can create custom function instead of init() method. Then call that function by button instance.

Comment: I'd go with an "Objective-C" way: Create a class method: static func customizedButton() -> UIButton { let button = UIButton(); button.backgroundColor = ...; return button }

Comment: @sagarChauhan I know, I am doing this for other functions but I only want to to this with the styling if there is now way to use the init like in my question. The custom function is only a backup way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do what you are trying to do. There are 2 interacting reasons for this.

1. You can't change a class' designated initializer from an extension.
2. You **can** create a convenience initializer in an extension, but a convenience initializer can't be an override of an existing initializer.

You are trying to redefine `init()`. You can't do that. You would need to create a convenience initializer that has different parameters than any existing initializer, and that convenience initializer  needs to ultimately call the designated initializer.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct Dummy { }

extension UIButton {
    convenience init(dummy: Dummy) {
        self.init()
        backgroundColor = InterfaceDesign.button.backgroundColor
        setTitleColor(InterfaceDesign.button.textColor, for: .normal)
    }
}

UIButton(dummy: Dummy())
```

Even though the above code formally answers the question, consider doing this instead:

```
extension UIButton {
    static var dummy: UIButton {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = InterfaceDesign.button.backgroundColor
        button.setTitleColor(InterfaceDesign.button.textColor, for: .normal)
        return button
    }
}

UIButton.dummy
```